# asp.net to html convert

Tags: asp.net, html, static, web, converters

I'm looking for some way to convert dynamic ASP.NET page to static html. I want to reduce costs of servers by converting it to static html page. 
Currently I'm checking, if HTTracker can help me, but maybe there is some better software.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than converting them to static HTML files, I would recommend caching your pages.

Your pages rendered output (the HTML) will then be stored and retrieved by other users until the cache expires.

This is basically doing what you require, but with the added benefit of an expiration.

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk(v=vs.100).aspx

---

If this is not an option you could always copy the rendered HTML from the page source of your browser, and paste that into a blank HTML file.

Comment: It's good solution, but f. e. on Amazon S3 I need to have html files.

Comment: @user1697273 Ah fair enough, in which case could you not just copy the HTML source from your browser? I'm assuming this is only a simple cheap website if these are your restrictions.

Comment: Well, let's say, that it's not a simple cheap website. It's generating great traffic, so I want to reduce cost by converting it to semi-static site. Rather than implementing whole page from the beginning, I would like to convert it with some tool and then do some refactoring.